# using a textbox to input the data in the scores textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is the right example
[image]

Need to use int data types.

SO, I am able to enter a number and but I get duplicate of a just one number.

Here is what I get on my code: [image]

```
       //create a string for the name 
        string name = txtName.Text;
        // create a int for the number 

        // have those now have to get three amounts 
        // for each name then store that 
        // make a size three array
        //innt to put the array in the for loop
        int[] x = new int[3];



        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            //txtScore.Text
            //txtStoreScores.Text
            int covert = Int32.Parse(txtScore.Text);
            x[i] = covert;
            txtStoreScores.AppendText(x[i].ToString());

            // ok I just need one number 
            // and split them by each number
        }
```

Comment: Why would you think a `for` loop is the right approach? Shouldn't the user input a number, then click the "Add Score" button, then the user would input the 2nd number, and then clicks then "Add Score" button again (rinse and repeat)?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Please state the question clearly.

Comment: Side note, you should probably add some sort of check and make sure your input is actually a number before parsing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, though you have selected an answer this feedback may be beneficial to future solutions.  Your button once triggered should fire an event, inside that could you want to ensure you properly sanitize user input.  Assume the user will cause an error, because the amount of variables they can input are infinite.

```
protected void btnAddScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(float.TryParse(txtGrade.Text, out grade) && grade >= 0)
          txtScores.Text += $"{grade}, ";
}
```

That simple conditional will sanitize, by ensuring that the user has entered a valid numeric and the score is higher than zero.  Especially since a negative number would be unlikely.  The primary point, your code should reflect the usage.   Your code should account for those anomalies and variances that may occur.

Another nifty notion, you are outputting directly based on input.  When you save that information, you would need to parse the data.  So realize that you may need to something along these lines:

```
var scores = txtScores.Text.Split(','); // An array.
txtScores.Text = String.Join(",", scores); // Converts array into single string
```

The problem will increase in complexity over time, so be aware of that.  Hopefully this was helpful.  As for your math, if you do the following it would calculate:

```
var sum = txtScores.Text.Split(", ").Sum(grade => (float)grade);
```

The above makes a potentially flawed assumption, that all would cast to a float without an issue.  These are items you need to think about. If you do not cast then your sum would be reflected by the length of your string not the values.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand this right!!! you want to append the number from txtScore to txtStoreScores each time you click Add Scores btn!!!!

in this case you don't need a loop, simply put this in Add Scores btn event handler
txtStoreScores.Text += txtScore.Text + " ";

you reaaaaaly need to give more details and a clear question. Good luck!

Comment: Ok yea it works but it needs to be an int data type to add up to the total score but it is a step in the  direction. Thank you!!